# How do you index a Set of UUIDs in Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, uuid, hibernate-search

I have an entity in my application, which has a `Set<UUID>` on it, which I would like to index.

So far, I've tried putting `@IndexEmbedded`, `@Field` and `@FieldBridge` (which takes a UUID, not `Set<UUID>`) annotations on the `Set<UUID>` with no effect. The Hibernate Search docs all show indexing `Set<X>` where `X` is another entity which is has annotations on for indexing.

I'm testing to see if it turns up in the index by setting a breakpoint in Netbeans and manually inspecting the lucene index on disk using Luke, to rule out writing an incorrect query. Other fields are being indexed fine and showing up in the index using this method.

I am using Hibernate Search 3.4 at this time, since it's part of an older application and cannot be easily upgraded.

Can anyone shed some light on the situation? I am beginning to suspect this is not supported, and the fastest way will be to change from `Set<UUID>` to `Set<Y>`, where `Y` is an entity that simply wraps the `UUID` for indexing, or writing a specific `FieldBridge` to handle the `Set<UUID>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need *@IndexedEmbedded*, but you will need a custom bridge. Something like this should work:

```
@Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = UUIDFieldBridge.class))
private Set<UUID> uuids;
```

It sounded like you already tried something like this. Did the bridge not even get called? Was there an exception?

Comment: I did end up making a custom `Set<UUID>` bridge implementation, and using that.